# Weird error when selecting more than 100 spark udf columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Starting with a simple spark dataframe with only one value, I create **N** simple udf columns.

```
N = 100
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([{'value': 0}])
udf_columns = [pyspark.sql.functions.udf(lambda x: 0)('value') for _ in range(N)]
df.select(udf_columns).take(1)
```

For N <= 100 this code works perfectly.
But as soon as N >= 101, I found the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 34.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 50, localhost): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: PythonUDF#<lambda>(input[0, LongType])
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable$class.genCode(Expression.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.PythonUDF.genCode(python.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$gen$2.apply(Expression.scala:104)
```